# How come I can't evaluate this particular integral? Why doesnt the u-substitution and reverse chain rule work?

Tags: integration

The following integral seems only possible to evaluate through expansion of the polynomial, which is easy. I plugged into integral calculators online with higher exponents of say 10 rather than 2, and they all choose to expand the polynomial. But is there no other way to evaluate it without expanding?

**Why doesnt u-substitution or reverse chain rule work for this?**

$$\int_{-1}^0(1-x^2)^2\ dx$$

Comment: You could substitute $x=\sin u$, $dx=\cos u\,du$, then you'd have to integrate high powers of $cosine$, for which there are reduction formulas. But I don't think that's any improvement on multiplying out the polynomial.

Comment: Integrating by parts twice is another option, giving$$\frac83 \int_{-1}^0 x^4 \, dx$$but that's arguably more work than expanding the polynomial.

Answer (score 1):

$$ \int_{-1}^{0} (1-x^2)^2 dx = \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^2 dx $$

Subtitute $x^2 = t$ then $x = \sqrt{t}$ and $dx = \frac{1}{2}t^{\frac{-1}{2}}dt$

Thus, we have

$$ \int_{0}^{1} (1-x^2)^2 dx = \frac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{1} t^{\frac{-1}{2}} (1-t)^2 dt = \frac{1}{2} B(1/2, 3)$$

$$\frac{1}{2} B(1/2, 3) = \frac{1}{2} \frac{2! \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{7}{2})} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{2\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\frac{5}{2} \times \frac{3}{2} \times \frac{1}{2} \Gamma(\frac{1}{2})} = \frac{1}{2} \frac{16}{15} = \frac{8}{15}$$

Comment: what do you call this method, and what is T or B for?

Comment: $B$ stands for the beta function whereas $\Gamma$ stands for the Gamma function.